# closeing a service by PendingIntent

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-pendingintent

i wanna close a service by clicking on an action in a notification.it seems that the only way to do that is using a PendingIntent . but my question is how can i close a service by a pending intent?do i have to start a broadcast or another service to close the first one or is there another way?

```
   Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Downloader.class);

    PendingIntent pi1 =PendingIntent.getService(this,i,intent1,0) ;

    mBuilder..addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_name, "close",pi1);
    mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: you can use the service you want to close and ask it to make a seppuku by calling `stopSelf`

Comment: can you tell me how?please

Comment: i already did: call `stopSelf` in your service

Comment: can you please write the code?

Comment: ok, what is unclear?

Comment: where do i call stopSelf

Comment: in your service, in a place where the service reads external intents sent by the clients

Comment: where?what do you mean?

Comment: where does it read external intent?

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics

Comment: so how can i know that intent is from notification?

Comment: by setting some "kill-yourself" intent extra?